# Pagination on db side vs application side

Tags: oracle, groovy, oracle11g

I have simple app which execute query on dp, since there are alot rows returned ~ 300-400k and its to much to be retrived and it cause `out of memory error` i have to use pagination. In `groovy.sql.SQL` we have `rows(String sql,int offset, int maxRows)` anyway its works very slow, for example with step 20k rows execution time of `rows` method starts with around 10 sec and increase with every next call, second way of achiving pagination is using some buile in mechanism for example

```
    select *
 from (
select /*+ first_rows(25) */
  your_columns,
  row_number() 
  over (order by something unique)rn
 from your_tables )
where rn between :n and :m 
order by rn;
```

And for my query second approach tooks 5 seconds with step 20k. My question is, which method is better for database? And what is the reason of slow execution `Sql.rows` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first_rows hint is no more needed - since Oracle 11g. For Oracle it is best approach producer-consumer design pattern. As database generates data "on-the-fly".

So simple pure select would be suitable:

```
select your_columns,
row_number() over (order by something unique)rn
from your_tables;
```

But unfortunately Java frameworks usually can not keep db connection open. They simply fetch all data at once, and then hand over the whole result set to caller.

You do not have many options. Either:

- you will need all lot of RAM to fetch everything. Plus you can also use lazy loading on JPA level.
- or you have to find a way how keep db connection open in a web application. Which it practically impossible. Also such a approach is not suitable for applications having more than thousands of concurrent users.

PS: under usual circumstances, the usual way how pagination is implemented does not return consistent data, as they can change between executions. So it should not be used for anything else that displaying purposes.

Comment: Hi  , In real life no one read ~ 300-400k row & understand , beyond 2 or 3 page data can't be understand by human.  So pls check your real use case. Most probably you might need to write this data in some text file and  show it as reports or plot graph or for some other post process analyze .   So clients shall read the data form this text file this would be good approach and it also give proper interface boundary form client & DB .

Comment: @ramki exactly i wany to generate report but i cant fetch all 300k rows at once so thats i want to check data in parts, thats why i;m asking which pagination is better

Comment: @whd, then you have hard work to do. Even iBatis, Hibernate or EclipseLink support producer-consumer design pattern. Due to Java limitations  (pre Java8 limitations) it is not straightforward at all. You have to somehow implement and register your callback classes. This really is not described in common JPA HOWTOs. PS: I do not know whether is this supported also by groovy.

Comment: You are talking about orm's or jpa, i woudl like to do it with purly jdbc, that way is harder?

Comment: @whd with pure JDBC you simply iterate and fetch rows from ResultSet. You just have to keep in mind, that you must not store all the rows in a container.

Comment: back to the post @ibre5041 you are saying that with such oracle pagination when im using `:n` and `:m` i may have duplicated rows?

Comment: @whd what I was trying to say is that unless you're using isolation level SERIALIZABLE, each execution, will see different data "snapshot" so your report will be based in "inconsistent" data. So for example a row is deleted, then consecutive might be listed twice.

Comment: Ok i understand, well that DB is being acutalized once per day so it wont be a problem.

Comment: hi , i am not getting how can you "check data in parts"  is it humanly possible to check ? In my opinion you have to still check with your use case .  All your check to get valid data for report shall be report condition.  i mean SQL where clause condition.

Comment: @Ramki it is programmically possible, and by this i mean i cant fetch all 300k rows because it fails with out of memory error

Comment: Hi , too avoid out memory only i am suggesting to write 300k rows in a file and load only currently viewing data in memory.